# How to make sense of a mulinomial regression output?

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, multinomial-distribution

I'm running a multinomial regression with the multinom() function. My three independent variables are ordinal categorical variables coded as follows:

```
rem$index_gdp <- factor(rem$index_gdp, levels = c("low_dependency", "medium_dependency", "high_dependency"), ordered=TRUE)
rem$index_v_dem<- factor(rem$index_v_dem, levels = c("low_dem", "med_dem", "high_dem"), ordered=TRUE)
rem$index_public <- factor(rem$index_public, levels = c("low_pub", "med_pub", "high_pub"), ordered=TRUE)
```

But when I run the regression, I obtain ".L" and ".Q", which I don't know how to interpret. How do I know what the reference category is?

````
Call:
multinom(formula = total_policy ~ index_gdp + index_v_dem + index_public, 
    data = rem)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept) index_gdp.L index_gdp.Q index_v_dem.L index_v_dem.Q index_public.L index_public.Q
1   37.489288   16.410803   -12.48258      12.34175      7.318490     11.4555042      -14.10284
2   36.608355   16.331964   -11.64787      13.13918      6.811164     11.9935756      -14.60239
3   28.407330   17.096411   -13.52100      12.51809      6.040052     -5.5547857      -24.59442
4    7.639698   -7.106567   -27.48203      38.83425     -7.389892      0.5846922      -20.55882

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept) index_gdp.L index_gdp.Q index_v_dem.L index_v_dem.Q index_public.L index_public.Q
1   176.53733    43.99783    15.07688      8.731736      5.115207     418.456867      241.26895
2   176.53755    43.99817    15.08551      8.741903      5.134716     418.456998      241.26906
3    17.74864    44.00171    15.08273      8.775134      5.161917       6.346047        3.37245
4   284.70862    96.18643    65.87118     96.313177     65.655168     805.179067      465.19839

Residual Deviance: 88.90863 
AIC: 144.9086 
```
````